# Ionic 4 does not detect orientation when opening the app

Tags: android, ios, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

My app is not detecting the orientation when I open the app, I have a method that gets the orientation and I call it when the view loads but it does not do anything, this is my code:

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
import { EventoDespacho } from './../../models/evento-despacho';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StatusBarStyleService } from '../../utils/status-bar-style.service';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { DespachoService } from 'src/app/api/despacho.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  isVertical: boolean;
  ngClasses: any;
  ngClassesButtonsCont: any;
  ngClassesButton: any;
  ngClassesSlider: any;
  imgServicios: string;
  imgTramites: string;
  imgLimpia: string;
  staticThis = this;
  backButtonSubscription: Subscription;
  titulo = 'Servicios Capital';

  constructor(
    private statusBarStyle: StatusBarStyleService,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private platform: Platform,
    private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Home ngOnInit');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.addEventListeners();
    this.statusBarStyle.setDarkStatusBar(this.statusBar);
    this.isVertical = true;
    this.ngClasses = {};
    this.ngClassesButtonsCont = {};
    this.ngClassesButton = {};
    this.ngClassesSlider = {};
    this.imgServicios = '';
    this.imgTramites = '';
    this.imgLimpia = '';
    this.onOrientationChange(null); 
  }

  ionViewDidLeave() {
    this.removeEventListeners();
  }

  /**
   * Atiende el evento cuando se presiona el backbutton del dispositivo.
   */
  onBackButtonClick() {
    navigator['app'].exitApp();
  }

  /**
   * Agrega los listeners de esta página.
   */
  addEventListeners() {
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.onOrientationChange);
    this.backButtonSubscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(
      this.onBackButtonClick
    );
  }

  /**
   * Remueve los listeners que pertenecen a esta página para evitar duplicidad.
   */
  removeEventListeners() {
    window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', this.onOrientationChange);
    this.backButtonSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  /**
   * Realiza cambios en íconos y clases de la pantalla al girar la pantalla.
   */
  onOrientationChange = event => {
    const orientation = screen.orientation.type.toString();

    this.isVertical = orientation.indexOf('portrait') >= 0;

    this.ngClasses = {
      'flex-c-col': this.isVertical,
      'flex-container-row': !this.isVertical
    };

    this.ngClassesButtonsCont = {
      'flex-container-row h-100': this.isVertical,
      'flex-c-col m-l-10': !this.isVertical
    };

    this.ngClassesButton = {
      'h-100': this.isVertical
    };

    this.ngClassesSlider = {
      'mw-50': !this.isVertical
    };

    if (this.isVertical) {
      this.imgServicios = '../../assets/images/BotonServiciosVertical.png';
      this.imgTramites = '../../assets/images/BotonTramitesVertical.png';
      this.imgLimpia = '../../assets/images/BotonLimpiaVertical.png';
    } else {
      this.imgServicios = '../../assets/images/BotonServicios.png';
      this.imgTramites = '../../assets/images/BotonTramites.png';
      this.imgLimpia = '../../assets/images/BotonLimpia.png';
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to set the orientation with `this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT_PRIMARY);` but this also didn't work.
One thing I noticed is that ngOnInit and ionViewDidLoad are not working when the view loads, I have to go to another view and return to the first one in order for this events to work, can anyone help me with this? Oh and this is only happening on iOS, android seems to work fine.